# IOException: error=7, Argument list too long with large command line

Tags: java, unix, process

I have a requirement to call Unix command from Java. The code is as follows.

```
String strCmd = "iconv -f "+ strSrcEncoding+" -t "+ strTgtEncoding + " <<< "+"\""+InputMessage+"\"";

String commands[] = {"bash","-c",strCmd};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
String strData = null;

// Get the error Stream
BufferedReader brStdError = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();


// read any errors from the attempted command
while ((strData = brStdError.readLine()) != null) {
    sbError.append(strData);
}

if(sbError.toString().isEmpty())
    return "success";
else
    return "failure"+sbError.toString();
```

When i pass a large data am getting an error

```
"bash": java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
```

I tried using echo instead as below

```
echo <<InputMessage>> | iconv -f utf8 -t Cp930
```

But was getting the same error

Am i missing anything?

Comment: You sure are missing something: mentioning that you pass the entire message to convert on the command line.

Comment: Try writing to the process input stream

Comment: @uncletall Can u elaborate. I am not sure on how to to write to process input stream

Answer (score 4):

There's a limit to much data you can pass to a program on the command line. If you have a lot of data you should pass it to iconv using its standard input stream, i.e. by writing it to `proc.getOutputStream`. Here's an example:

```
OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
os.write(InputMessage.getBytes(strSrcEncoding));
os.close();
```

Unfortunately, for longer messages this will also fail because `iconv` will fill the buffer of the pipe it is connected to, and wait for the pipe to be read. The solution is writing data to `iconv` from one thread and reading the output from another. Dealing with external processes is a hassle because of all these pit-falls. You can read more about it here: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html [Apache commons exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) helps you deal with some of them.

On the other hand, why are you using iconv? You know Java has good library support for most character encodings, `cp930` included?

Comment: I tried encoding in Java. The above code is used to check if the message can be encoded to Cp930 or not. When tested the same from java, the results were different from that when executed iconv command, so i had left with no option but to call unix commands from Java

Comment: Can u elaborate pass it to iconv using its standard input stream, i.e. by writing it to proc.getOutputStream

Answer (score 2):

This happens, when the size of the arguments exceeds the allowed size. And this depends on the platform.

To verify the maximum limit, run

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

For mac osx environment, I can see 262144 is the limit.

Limit for each platform is different, that can be found here:
[http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/)

To check the environment string:

```
$ env
```

Answer (score 1):

I reached this issue when trying to set environment variables as follows:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(...);
pb.environment().putAll(env); //here it's ok
...
pb.start(); //here is where it throws the exception
```

The problem was with what the `env` map contained, though the `"bash":java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long` was indicating otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for that reply in our particular case when seeing this error this was the problem. Pity its obscured by the argument too long red herring.