# IOException when executing shell script via PDI/Kettle

Tags: java, linux, pentaho, etl, kettle

I am executing a shell script via the "Execute a shell script..." step in PDI/Kettle, however, I am observing a strange behavior.

Whenever I execute the job where the "Execute a shell script..." step is located in on its own, everything works just fine and my shell script is called.

Once I execute a wrapper job though (that calls the job with the shell script as a subjob) I am getting the following error message when the script is executed:

```
2016/08/19 15:21:13 - Export schema file - Running on platform : Linux
2016/08/19 15:21:13 - Export schema file - Executing command : /opt/XXX/pdi/remote-service/unix_execute-remote-service.sh 4 XXX yyy authentication localhost 80 admin admin http
2016/08/19 15:21:13 - Export schema file - ERROR (version 3.2.5 from 2016-02-23 08.24.59) : Error running shell [/opt/XXX/pdi/remote-service/unix_execute-remote-service.sh] : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/XXX/pdi/remote-service/unix_execute-remote-service.sh": error=7, Argument list too long
```

I don't understand where this problem is coming from, as executing the script on it's own works just fine. The log also prints out the exact command that is supposed to be executed and when I copy this into a shell manually, I can execute it...

Any ideas? I am really stumped on this one...

Comment: Try to run *getconf ARG_MAX* and check the max size of argument you can have on the system, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912103/java-bash-java-io-ioexception-error-7-argument-list-too-long)

Comment: Did that, the value that is returned is 2097152. Not sure that unit this is in (byte, kilobyte, characters, ...?), but regardless, this should be large enough. It's only 9 parameters in plain text, no files or anything are being passed. So I don't think that this can be the issue? Plus I can execute the exact command (it's given in the log) just fine in a shell on that server?!

Comment: [Here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax) you could find a full explanation. It's not just your script arguments, you have to check your env variables as explained in the doc I link.

Comment: I am not setting any env variables, at least not that I am aware of. The only thing the script does it execute a java command. Thanks for the document, I'll have a read, but I can't see any solution in there. Is there a possibility to "flush" the env variables before executing a script? Maybe I could try that...

Comment: Are you sure your script is taking just few arguments as you wrote? Try to check the way your script is called, printing out the actual command executed. Maybe some *\* or some new line missed could enqueue more than you want.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It only takes these 9 arguments. The script itself will set a JAVA_HOME environment variable and the CLASSPATH, but that's about it. After that it just collects the arguments passed to the shell with $@ and calls a .jar file. In the log you can see it's only these 9 arguments passed to the shell...

Comment: Another possibility is that the *Argument too long* error is just caused of your *java.io.IOException*  and not the root cause. So you should try to get the full exception text. Please update your OP with that infos.